# jcmd - Meaning of last colum for `jcmd VM.flags -all`

Tags: java, jvm, jdk-tools, jcmd

Run following command to list all available jvm flags:

```
jcmd 24468 VM.flags -all | less -N
```

Then in last column, found following values *(using JDK1.8, on linux)*:

```
* product
    default value is the same on all platform,
* pd product
    default value is platform-dependent,
* manageable
    could change dymanically in runtime,
* 
* C1 product
* C2 product
* 
* C1 pd product
* C2 pd product
* 
* product rw
* 
* lp64_product
* ARCH product
* 
* commercial
*
```

**The question is:**

I only know the meaning of some values, which I have give explanation, what are the meaning of the rest ones?

Comment: I think `jcmd` topic is too narrow for a separate tag. Something common like `jdk-tools` would suit better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of a flag depends on a location in HotSpot source code where the flag is declared / defined. Most flags are declared in [src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp#l499).

- `pd_product` flags are also declared in globals.hpp, but defined in one of platform-dependent files:

  - [src/cpu/x86/vm/globals_x86.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/cpu/x86/vm/globals_x86.hpp#l31)
  - [src/os/linux/vm/globals_linux.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/os/linux/vm/globals_linux.hpp#l28)
  - [src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm/globals_linux_x86.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/os_cpu/linux_x86/vm/globals_linux_x86.hpp#l28)
- `C1 product` and `C2 product` flags are specific to C1 (client) and C2 (server) compiler respectively. They are declared in files

  - [src/share/vm/c1/c1_globals.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/share/vm/c1/c1_globals.hpp#l57)
  - [src/share/vm/opto/c2_globals.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/share/vm/opto/c2_globals.hpp#l57)
- `C1 pd product` and `C2 pd product` are those C1/C2 flags defined in platform-specific directories (os, cpu, os_cpu).
- `product rw` flags are similar to `manageable`, but intended for internal use and subject to change in future versions of JVM. These flags can also be modified in run-time via JMX.
- `lp64_product` flags exist only in 64-bit JVM. In 32-bit JVM they are compile-time constants.
- `ARCH product` flags exist only on particular architecture, unlike `pd_product` that exist everywhere but differ in default value. Architecture-specific flags are declared and defined in [src/cpu/x86/vm/globals_x86.hpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/2b2511bd3cc8/src/cpu/x86/vm/globals_x86.hpp#l87).
- `commercial` flags require `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` option.

There are also

- `diagnostic` flags for use by JVM developers.
  They are unlocked by `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions`.
- `experimental` flags for features that are not fully tested/supported.
  They are unlocked by `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`.